# Comparing Elements in the same ArrayLists and add to Hashmap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, compare

I got a quick question.

Currently, I have a userList (of `String`) and timeLime (of `Integer`).
These values were added in order and therefore each `.get(i)` will contain the user (`userList`) with his time (`timeList`).

As there may be duplicate instances of users in the name `ArrayList`, I would like to sum up the total time for each user in `timeList` and put it to a hashmap of `<String, Integer>`, but I do not know how to do it.

Currently, what I have done is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++) {
    count = 0; 
    for (int j = 0; j <userList.size(); j++) {
        if (!userList.get(i).equals(userList.get(j))) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == userList.size() -1) {
        System.out.println("Adding in " + userList.get(i));
        map.put(userList.get(i), timeList.get(i));
    }
}
```

I am stuck till the point where if there is a match. I do not know how to add the time together and put it in the hashmap.

I'm not very proficient in Java and would like some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean sum up total time?? Is all what you want to achieve: remove the duplicates and count how many distinct element there are?

Comment: @lostcder add an example of possible Input and desirable Output.

Comment: @Alboz:
For example. I have a duplicate entry of Peter in nameList but with different time (200, 308). I would like to add (Peter, 508) into the hashmap. But I will also want to add all non-duplicated entries too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to create one HashMap with user and the sum of time that may appear anywhere in the two lists? If that is the case, the following code will do it for you.

```
    List<String> userList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("ann", "john", "tim", "ann"));
    List<Integer> timeList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 5));

    Map<String, Integer> userTimeMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++) {
        String user = userList.get(i);
        Integer time = userTimeMap.get(user);
        if (time == null) {
            userTimeMap.put(user, timeList.get(i));
        } else {
            userTimeMap.put(user, time + timeList.get(i));
        }
    }
```

> Result : {john=2, ann=6, tim=3}

Comment: Hi maheeka, thank you for response. This set of codes actually works. But just wondering, if a key exists in a hashmap, does adding the same key to the hashmap overwrite the current key? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it does overwrite any previous content saved with same key with the new value. Please vote up :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++) {
    // check whether the entry is already there
    if (map.containsKey(userList.get(i))){
        // If already exists add
        map.put(userList.get(i), map.get(userList) + timeList.get(i));
    }else{
        // else make a new entry
        map.put(userList.get(i), timeList.get(i));
    }
}
```